# Run Ansible playbook without inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Consider if I want to check something quickly. Something that doesn't really need connecting to a host (to check how `ansible` itself works, like, including of handlers or something). Or `localhost` will do. I'd probably give up on this, but man page says:

> `-i PATH, --inventory=PATH`
>
> The PATH to the inventory, which defaults to /etc/ansible/hosts. **Alternatively**, you can use a comma-separated
> list of hosts or a single host with a trailing comma host,.

And when I run `ansible-playbook` without inventory, it says:

> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only **localhost** is available

Is there an easy way to run playbook against no host, or probably `localhost`?

Comment: I use `echo 'localhost' > hosts.ini`, because my real inventories are partitioned in production, reference, testing and development.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Prerequisites. You need to have `ssh` server running on the host (`ssh localhost` should let you in).

Then if you want to use password authentication (do note the **trailing comma**):

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i localhost, -k
```

In this case you also need `sshpass`.

In case of public key authentication:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i localhost,
```

And the test playbook, to get you started:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug: msg=test
```

You need to have a comma in the `localhost,` option argument, because otherwise it would be treated as a path to an inventory. The inventory plugin responsible for parsing the value can be found [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.13.2/lib/ansible/plugins/inventory/host_list.py).

Comment: -k asks for a password (I don't know why that's part of the answer).  in any case `-i localhost` doesn't work because one is supposed to pass in an inventory source, not a host name.  I get: "[WARNING]: Unable to parse /Users/ekkis/dev/x/ansible-blockchain-node/localhost as an inventory source"

Comment: @ekkis `-i localhost` isn't supposed to work, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a default inventory with only localhost

See it is explained here:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file

And in your playbook add use this

```
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - debug: msg=test
```

It will use local connection so no SSH is required (thus it doesn't expose your machine). It might be quicker unless you need to troubleshoot a ssh issue.

Also for quicker feedback loop you can use: `gather_facts: no` you already know your target.